# VSC keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I have tried to implement this feature for a long time.  I have not been able to find answers online.  I would like to use **"Tab"** key to do two things.

> 1. I want to indent if cursor is at the beginning of a line, or
> 2. jump to end of line if cursor is between characters/strings.

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+tab",
        "command": "tab",
        "when": "editorFocus && inputFocus && !editorHasSelection"
    },
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "cursorEnd",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }
]
```

*These are similar features that are in Eclipse and Intellij IDE*

Comment: install intellij ide keymapping extension on vs code

Comment: You can't do that in vscode without an extension.  There are no `when` clauses that can indicate position in a line.   I looked through the intellij ide keymapping extension but searching for `tab` showed no `go to the end of the line` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by modifying the extension TabOut, which indents except when the cursor is next to a bracket or brace, in which case it tabs through.

If you instead of a brace, you make it behave that way next to any character except newlines, it should jump to end of line.